# Calculating $\lim_{x\to0} \left\lfloor\frac{x^2}{\sin x \tan x}\right\rfloor$

Tags: calculus, limits

> Find $$\lim_{x\to0}  \left\lfloor\frac{x^2}{\sin x \tan x}\right\rfloor$$ where $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ is greatest integer function

I am a high school teacher. One of my students came up to ask this limit. 
For $\lfloor\frac{\sin x}{x}\rfloor$, I have used $\sin x > x$ using increasing decreasing functions.

I tried to prove $x^2 > \sin x \tan x$ using increasing /decreasing
 function but I am not getting it.

Comment: [Please see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for a guide to writing math with MathJax, and [see here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) for a guide to formatting posts with Markdown.

Comment: am new to stack exchange it is limit x->o integral part of (x^2 /sinx.tanx)

Comment: $\sin x < x$ if $x>0$

Answer (score 13):

Apply GM - HM to $\sin x$ and $\tan x$ (both positive for $x\geq 0$), we get that

$$ \sqrt{ \sin x \tan x } \geq \frac{2} { \frac{1} {\sin x} + \frac{ 1}{ \tan x} } = \frac{2 \sin x} { 1 + \cos x } = 2 \tan \frac{x}{2} \geq x$$

The only 'calc' that you need is the last inequality, though it has an easy geometric solution.

For $x < 0$, both $\sin x, \tan x$ have the same sign, and you can do the above with absolute values instead, no difference.

Comment: note that : $x\neq 0$ Because $\sin 0=\tan 0=0$ So $\dfrac{1}{\sin x},\dfrac{1}{\tan x} =\text{Undefined}$

Answer (score 11):

Consider the function
$$f(x) = \frac{x^2\cos(x)}{\sin^2(x)}$$
Then we have that
$$f(x+h)\approx \cos(x) < 1$$
for every $h\neq 0$ with $|h|$ small enough. Thus the limit converges to $0$.

---

We want to show that $f(x)<1$ for $|x|\neq0$ small enough. We will do so by showing that $g(x) = \sin^2(x)>x^2\cos(x)=h(x)$. The two functions agree in $0$, thus it is enough to show that $g'(x)>h'(x)$ for $x>0$ (we don't have to consider $x<0$, since both $g$ and $h$ are even functions).
$$g'(x) = 2\sin(x)\cos(x)$$
$$h'(x) = x\cos(x)-x^2\sin(x)$$
Since both agree in $0$ (again) we can consider the next derivative:
$$g''(x) = 2(\cos^2(x) - \sin^2(x))$$
$$h''(x) = \cos(x) - x(3\sin(x) -x\cos(x))$$
Notice that $g''(0)=2>1=h''(0)$, thus by continuity of both functions there is a neighborhood of $0$ where $g''>h''$, and we're done.

Comment: Put my answer together with the one of Omnomnomnom to get a complete solution.

Comment: But $x^2/\sin^2x$ is more than 1, and it's not clear (certainly in high school maths) which dominates.

Comment: Is there a way to show that $\frac{x}{\sin x}\to 1$ faster than $\cos(x)$?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Looking at the Taylor expansion does the job: $\frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1 - \frac{x^2}{6} + O(x^4)$, thus $\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2} = 1 - \frac{x^2}{3}+O(x^4)$, while $\cos(x) = 1-\frac{x^2}{2}+O(x^4)$.

Comment: I am high school level so my students know basics of limits, continuity and differentiability. is there any way without Taylor series, by simply proving that numerator is > or < denominator,such that floor function gives zero or one

Comment: for x/sinx , i use g(x) = sinx - x and prove that sinx - x is decreasing function so sinx < x for x>0

Comment: @raj I don't know. You could try to differentiate $f$ and show that $sgn(x)f'(x)>0$ for $|x|$ small enough, but I suspect it would be a mess...

Comment: @raj Maybe I've got another way. I'll edit my answer if I get something.

Comment: @Daniel i am trying to do that but f′(x) in this case not so neat and i cannot definitely say f′(x)>0 or <0

Comment: @raj I'm stuck... If I come up with something I'll let you know, else you can always explain Taylor series to your students, they aren't all that hard ;)

Comment: @raj Ok, take a look now. I'm a bit tired, so my explanation could be unclear (or, god forbid, wrong). Let me know if you need clarifications.

Answer (score 8):

So first of all, note that
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^2}{\sin x \tan x}=\dots=
\left(\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{\sin x}\right)^2
\left(\lim_{x\to 0}\cos(x)\right)=1
$$
Now, this doesn't necessarily tell us anything about the original function, since the greatest integer function is not continuous. So, we actually have three possibilities:

- if $x^2\geq\sin x \tan x$ in a sufficiently small neighborhood of $x=0$, then the limit is $1$.
- if $x^2<\sin x \tan x$ in a sufficiently small neighborhood of $x=0$, then the limit is $0$.
- if neither of the above is true, the limit does not exist.

So, we must find out: which is it?

---

Here's an attempt to show that the limit becomes $0$:
$$
\begin{align}
x^2 &< \sin x \tan x\\
x^2\cos x &< \sin^2 x \\
x^2\cos x &<\frac12 (1-\cos(2x))\\
2x^2\cos x &< (1-\cos(2x))\\
2x^2\cos x + \cos(2x) &< 1\\
\end{align}
$$
From there, it might be possible to make an argument using Taylor series.

Comment: thanks a lot , but i cannot use Taylor series

Answer (score 2):

Since you already know how get the limit without the floor function, I will try to prove that inequality without Taylor series.

$$x^2<\sin x \tan x \quad as \; x \to 0$$

I made the substitution $x \to \arctan x$ .

$\arctan^2 x<x\sin (\arctan x)$

$\arctan x < \large \frac{x}{(x^2+1)^{\frac 14}}$

There are two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ . $f(0)=g(0)$ . If $f'(x)>g'(x)$ on the interval $(0, a)$ , then that implies that $f(x)>g(x)$ on the interval $(0, a)$ . Therefore if $RHS'>LHS'$ , then $RHS>LHS$ .

$\large \large \large \frac {1}{x^2+1} <\frac {x^2+2}{2(x^2+1)^{\frac 54}}$

$1<\large \frac {x^2+2}{2(x^2+1)^{\frac 14}}$

Using standard techniques (such as first derivative test) we can show that the $RHS$ has a minimum at $(0, 1)$ so we have proved the inequality. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

First let us investigate the limit without the floor function:

We already know that
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x}= \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x}{\sin(x)}=1$$

So we can easily rewrite
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x^2}{\sin(x)\tan(x)}$$
as
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \left(\frac{x}{\sin(x)}\right)^2\left(\frac{\cos(x)}{1}\right)$$
$$= \lim_{x\to 0} \left(\frac{\cos(x)}{1}\right)=1$$

Case 1: If $0<x<\frac{\pi}{6}$ then $x>\sin(x)$
now let
$$f(x)=x^2-\sin(x)\tan(x)$$

Bear with me as this is slightly long, I used symbolab to calculate the $n^{th}$ derivatives of $f(x)$

$$f'(x)=2x-\sin(x)(1+\sec^2(x))$$
$$f''(x)=2-\cos(x)-\sec(x)-2\sec^2(x)\tan(x)\sin(x)$$
$$f'''(x)=\sin(x)-sec(x)\tan(x)-2[\alpha]$$
where $\alpha$ is a positive expression when $x\in [0,\frac{\pi}{6}]$.

Clearly, and since  $\sec(x)>1$ over this interval,
$$\sin(x)-\sec(x)\tan(x)<\tan(x)-\sec(x)\tan(x)<0$$

which means that $f'''(x)<0$ and that $f''(x)$ is decreasing.

Now since $f''(0)=0$ and $f''(x)$ is decreasing over this interval, then $f''(x)<0$ which means that $f'(x)$ is decreasing

$f'(0)=0$ and $f'(x)$ is decreasing means that $f'(x)<0$ and, hence, $f(x)$ is decreasing

last but not least, knowing that $f(x)=0$ and $f(x)$ is decreasing lead us to conclude that $f(x)<0$
$$i.e.\;\; x^2<\sin(x)\tan(x)$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{x^2}{\sin(x)\tan(x)}<1$$

And, hence, for a sufficiently small $x>0$
$$\left\lfloor \left(\frac{x}{\sin(x)}\right)^2\left(\frac{\cos(x)}{1}\right)\right\rfloor=0$$

Finally, and given that the function in question is an even function
i.e.
$$\left(\frac{-x}{\sin(-x)}\right)^2\left(\frac{\cos(-x)}{1}\right)= \left(\frac{x}{\sin(x)}\right)^2\left(\frac{\cos(x)}{1}\right)$$

We conclude that

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \left\lfloor \left(\frac{x}{\sin(x)}\right)^2\left(\frac{\cos(x)}{1}\right)\right\rfloor=0$$

Comment: How are you justifying the step from $\sin x<x$, $\cos x<1$ to $\color{red}{\left(\frac{x}{\sin x}\right)^{2}}\color{blue}{\left(\frac{\cos x}{1}\right)}<1$ ? This is nonobvious. You are multiplying a term $\color{red}{u}>1$ by a term $\color{blue}{v}<1$, so you could potentially have $\color{red}{u}\color{blue}{v}>1$, depending on which contributes more. Indeed, this is the case if you had taken $\left(\frac{x}{\sin x}\right)^{\color{brown}{4}}\left(\frac{\cos x}{1}\right)$, which *is* greater than $1$.

Comment: You have $b/a$.

Comment: true! nice catch, let me try to see if I can salvage this :)

Comment: Fixed, do me a favour and double check if you have the time. and again, thx for catching the error.

Answer (score 1):

Let $[.]$ denote GIF.

If $x \to 0$, then $\sin x=x-x^3/6+O(x^5)$ and $\tan x =x+x^3/3+O(x^4)$
then $$f(x)=\left(\frac{x^2}{\sin x \tan x}\right)=\left(\frac{x^2}{x^2(1-x^2/6+...)(1+x^2/3+...)}\right)=\left(\frac{1}{1+x^2/6-x^4/18}\right)$$
Using $(1+z)^k =1+kz+O(z^2)$, we can write

$$1-x^2/6 \le f(x) \le 1-x^2/6+x^4/18 \implies [1-x^2/6] \le [f(x)] \le [1-x^2/6+x^4/18].$$
Hence $$\lim_{x\to 0} [f(x)]=0.$$