# Prove that $x^2<\sin x \tan x$ as $x \to 0$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, trigonometry, inequality

$$x^2<\sin x \tan x \quad as \; x \to 0$$

I made the substitution $x \to \arctan x$ .

$\arctan^2 x<x\sin (\arctan x)$

$\arctan x < \large \frac{x}{(x^2+1)^{\frac 14}}$

There are two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ . $f(0)=g(0)$ . If $f'(x)>g'(x)$ on the interval $(0, a)$ , then that implies that $f(x)>g(x)$ on the interval $(0, a)$ . Therefore if $RHS'>LHS'$ , then $RHS>LHS$ .

$LHS'=\large \large \large \frac {1}{x^2+1} <RHS'=\frac {x^2+2}{2(x^2+1)^{\frac 54}}$

$\large \large \large \frac {1}{x^2+1}<\frac {x^2+2}{2(x^2+1)^{\frac 54}}$

$1<\large \frac {x^2+2}{2(x^2+1)^{\frac 14}}$

Using standard techniques (such as first derivative test) we can show that the $RHS$ has a minimum at $(0, 1)$ so we have proved the inequality.

I have two questions:

$1)$ Is my proof correct?

$2)$ Are there nicer ways of doing this inequality (without involving math higher than calc 1)? I have tried AM-GM and others but I think it is very hard to do it very elegantly because the $RHS$ is such a good approximation of the $LHS$ as $x \to 0$ .

Comment: Is the Taylor expansion beyond calc 1?

Comment: > If the RHS>LHS, this implies that $\frac{d}{dx}RHS>\frac{d}{dx}LHS$

This is not correct.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes, I haven't learned that yet

Comment: RHS>LHS does not imply RHS' >LHS'. See for $x+2>x$

Comment: @nimish I think that at least in this case it does. You have two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ . $f(0)=g(0)$ . If $f'(x)>g'(x)$ on the interval $(0, a)$ doesn't that imply that $f(x)>g(x)$ on the interval $(0, a)$?

Comment: What OP has works, though should be rewritten. $\frac{d}{dx} RHS > \frac{d}{dx} LHS$ and $ RHS(0) = LHS(0)$ implies that $RHS > LHS$ for $x\geq 0$.

Comment: [This answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/442846/12042) also gives an elementary proof.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Haha that was the question I was trying to answer

Comment: I did wonder whether there was a connection.

Comment: Logic of the argument is done backwards, needs to be corrected. One cannot prove  $A$ by showing that $A$ after some manipulation leads to something correct.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I corrected it, is that better?

Comment: @whoever-voted-to-close the other question only partly answers mine; it gives me only one other method to solve this, and it doesn't answer the question weather my proof is correct or not.

Comment: @CalvinLin I fixed that, but do you think there is an easy approach which uses clever inequality techniques?

Comment: Better, the fix in the paragraph is good. Beware of bare inequalities, like the ones below the modified paragraph.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Ok i fixed it again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apply GM - HM to $\sin x$ and $\tan x$ (both positive for $x\geq 0$), we get that

$$ \sqrt{ \sin x \tan x } \geq \frac{2} { \frac{1} {\sin x} + \frac{ 1}{ \tan x} } = \frac{2 \sin x} { 1 + \cos x } = 2 \tan \frac{x}{2} \geq x$$

The only 'calc' that you need is the last inequality, but that has an easy graphical approach too.

Comment: +1 Very nice, this is what I was looking for

Comment: @Ovi Thanks. As you can see, the LHS is the product of 2 terms, which motivates using GM-HM.

Answer (score 1):

The arctan substitution is a strictly monotone change of variable near the origin and therefore the string of inequalities are all equivalent to each other, so modulo checking the algebra the approach appears to be correct.  Without necessarily knowing about Taylor series one could try to show that $\sin x \geq x - \frac{x^3}{6}$ while $\tan x > x + \frac{x^3}{3}$ from which the formula follows by algebra.