# Prove that $\frac{1}{\sin t} - \frac{1}{t}$ is increasing on $(0,\pi/2)$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I would like to obtain a rigorous proof of the fact that
$$
\frac{1}{\sin t} - \frac{1}{t}
$$
is increasing on $(0,\pi/2)$. I attempted the usual by taking the derivative and seeing if it's positive, however, this led me nowhere enlightening. Is it possibly related to the fact that $\sin x \leq x$ for all $0 \leq x \leq \pi/2$? This isn't a homework problem, so I would not mind a full solution. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This seems a bit delicate.  Peter Tamaroff's answer was hasty.

Comment: I agree that this does seem to be delicate. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Taking the derivative, you want to show that

$$ \frac{ - \cos t } { \sin^2 t } + \frac{1}{t^2 } \geq 0  \Leftrightarrow \tan t \sin t \geq t^2 $$

There are many ways to prove this, like in this [other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/443586/prove-that-x2-sin-x-tan-x-as-x-to-0/443607#443607).

Comment: I like how this is slick and essentially only a couple lines assuming the knowledge of GM - HM. Very nice! I am having great difficulty deciding which solution I like the most... hah.

Answer (score 3):

$$
\text{derivative} = \frac{-\cos t}{\sin^2 t} + \frac{1}{t^2} =\frac{-t^2\cos t + \sin^2 t}{\text{something positive}}
$$
$$
\text{the numerator} = -t^2\left(1 - \frac{t^2}{2}+\text{higher-degree terms}\right) + \left(t^2 - \frac{t^4}3 + \text{higher-degree terms}\right)
$$
$$
= \frac{t^4}{12} + \text{higher-degree terms}
$$

This shows at least that the derivative is positive if $t$ is close enough to $0$.  To get all the way up to $\pi/2$ will take more work.  Showing that the second derivative is positive will do it.

Answer (score 2):

All inequalities are meant to be taken over $(0,\pi/2)$. The inequalities involving Taylor polynomials can be proven using the remainder which is either negative or positive in $(0,\pi/2)$.

Note that we can try and prove $$\left(\frac{\sin t}t\right)^2>\cos t$$

We use $1-\dfrac {t^2}2+\dfrac {t^4}{24}>\cos t$, so we aim to prove $${\left( {\frac{{\sin t}}{t}} \right)^2} > 1 - \frac{{{t^2}}}{2} + \frac{{{t^4}}}{{24}}$$
This is equivalent to showing $${\sin ^2}t > {t^2} - \frac{{{t^4}}}{2} + \frac{{{t^6}}}{{24}}$$ But $$\sin^2 t> t^2- \frac{t^4} 3$$

Then we have to show $${t^2} - \frac{{{t^4}}}{3} > {t^2} - \frac{{{t^4}}}{2} + \frac{{{t^6}}}{{24}}$$ or what is the same $$\frac{{{t^4}}}{6} > \frac{{{t^6}}}{24}$$

to be positive on $(0,\pi/2)$. And this is true.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo I think we can delete old comments.

Comment: Ah, nice.${}{}$

Comment: @AndresCaicedo =)

Comment: @PeterTamaroff Deleted them.

Comment: @CalvinLin The difference is $0.39$, approximately.

Comment: @CalvinLin Sorry, it should read $4!$, not $4$. =)

Comment: @PeterTamaroff Haha, thanks! I jumped to the last line as I recall that others were having issues with this Taylor approximation method. Good to know that it works over the entire range.

Comment: @CalvinLin The point is the difference is quite big, so we can fit some polynomials nicely between them. ;)

Comment: @PeterTamaroff I like how this one does not require anything fancy. The only thing is, should it be $t^4/6$ in the last line other than $t^4/3$?

Comment: @PeterTamaroff, it is not necessary to use the Taylor expansion in this problem. It would make this problem harder.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Maple to examine the claim's correctness as well.

```
[> f:=t->1/sin(t)-1/t:
[> solve(diff(f(t),t)>0,t);

       RealRange(Open(-Pi), Open(0)), RealRange(Open(0), Open(Pi))
```

Comment: Looks good to me! $\;{\tiny +^1}\;\ddot\smile$

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks to see you on. However, it just shows the claim machinery and doesn't solve the problem formally. :-)

Comment: Good to see you, too! Regarding your comment: Of course, but Maple and other such software helps shed insight on the problem! ;-)