# Proving the inequality $\frac{\tan{x}}{x} > \frac{x}{\sin{x}}$

Tags: calculus, functions, inequality

I'm trying to prove this inequality:
$$\frac{\tan{x}}{x} > \frac{x}{\sin{x}} $$
for all $x$ in $(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$.

I tried analyzing the derivates, but that's just making it more complicated. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/443586/prove-that-x2-sin-x-tan-x-as-x-to-0?rq=1

Comment: Question [443586](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/443586/prove-that-x2-sin-x-tan-x-as-x-to-0?rq=1) itself is not a duplicate, but one of the answers answers exactly this question, namely Calvin's [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/443607/55235). I'm therefore voting to close as a duplicate.

Comment: f(x)=tan(x)/x-x/sin(x) with x in (0;pi/2); f is continuos and differentiable in the domain; if x->0+ f(x)->0 and f'(x)>0 in the domain.

Answer (score 7):

One has
$${\sin x\over x}=\int_0^1\cos(t x)\ dt,\quad{\tan x\over x}=\int_0^1{1\over\cos^2(tx)}\ dt\qquad\left(0<x<{\pi\over2}\right)\ .$$
By Schwarz' inequality this implies
$${\sin x\over x}{\tan x\over x}\geq \left(\int_0^1{1\over\sqrt{\cos(tx)}}\ dt\right)^2>1\qquad\left(0<x<{\pi\over2}\right)\ .$$