# What is the value of $\lim _{x\to 0}\left\lfloor\frac{\tan x \sin x}{x^2}\right\rfloor$

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry, ceiling-and-floor-functions

How do I evaluate the limit

$$\lim _{x\to 0}\left\lfloor\frac{\tan x \sin x}{x^2}\right\rfloor$$ 
where $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ denotes greatest integer function.
I know that $x>\sin x$ and $x < \tan x$ but how do I use these results here?
$\tan x \over x$ tends to $1+$ whereas $\sin x \over x$ tends to $1-$

Comment: To dheeraj is your question is $\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\lfloor \frac{\tan x\sin x}{x^2} \rfloor $, Where $\lfloor x \rfloor $ represent floor function of $x$

Comment: Yah There is a greatest integer function.

Comment: Then answer is $=1$

Comment: How do we determine that ? As one quantity tries to reduce the value and the other tries to increase it.

Comment: Using $f(x) = \tan x\sin x-x^2$

Comment: Rather split $x^2=x.x$ and use our normal results

Comment: see http://math.stackexchange.com/q/442831/72031 and http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1052492/72031

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Taylor–Young expansions: we know that
$$\tan(x)=x+\frac{x^3}3+o(x^4),\qquad\sin(x)=x-\frac{x^3}6+o(x^4),$$
hence
$$\tan(x)\sin(x)=x^2+\frac{x^4}6+o(x^5),$$
and hence
$$\frac{\tan(x)\sin(x)}{x^2}=1+\frac{x^2}6+o(x^3).$$
From here, we conclude that there exists a punctured neighborhood $V$ of $0$ such that
$$\forall x\in V,\ \frac{\tan(x)\sin(x)}{x^2}>1.$$
Since
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan(x)\sin(x)}{x^2}=1$$
we can assume that $V$ has been chosen such that
$$\forall x\in V,\ 1<\frac{\tan(x)\sin(x)}{x^2}<2.$$
Hence
$$\forall x\in V,\ \left\lfloor\frac{\tan(x)\sin(x)}{x^2}\right\rfloor=1,$$
from which we conclude that
$$\lim_{x\to0}\left\lfloor\frac{\tan(x)\sin(x)}{x^2}\right\rfloor=1.$$